# Getting the text till a particular character after the regex match in java

Tags: java, regex

I need to get the text that follows the regex matched text till particular character.

For example, consider this line:

```
*?ref_=xoxoxo"><img src="*http://www.wow-how.com/yaba-daba-doo.jpg"
```

here ?ref_=xoxoxo"> will be regex matched and i need to get the text after this regex match  that is http://www.wow-how.com/yaba-daba-doo.jpg till the character "

Please note that the

How to do this? Kindly help.

Comment: I havent really tried much. Iam new to regex and i needed help to solve this small problem in my project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a lookbehind,

```
(?<=\\?ref_=xoxoxo\"><img src=\"\\*)[^\"]*
```

Code:

```
String s = "*?ref_=xoxoxo\"><img src=\"*http://www.wow-how.com/yaba-daba-doo.jpg\"";
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\?ref_=xoxoxo\"><img src=\"\\*)[^\"]*");
Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(s);
while(matcher.find()){
       System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
    }
```

Output:

```
http://www.wow-how.com/yaba-daba-doo.jpg
```

Comment: Thanks Avinash! This was exactly what i wanted. Could you suggest me some good sources to learn regex, especially lookaround?